# Detecting if html() is loaded in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i check if one html is being fully loaded ? And then i want to do something. If:

```
$('#load').html(1);
```

is ended i want to wait couple of seconds and then load another

```
$('#load').html(2);
```

How can i see when an html is being fully loaded ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`html()` is a synchronous operation.

The second html function wont start until the first is complete. Unless the html is loading some dynamic content?

EDIT:
It is loading dynamic content. In which case you could do this instead:

```
$('#load').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
    // callback runs when first load is finished
    $('#load').load('ajax/test2.html');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i set some timeout and the wanted effect is on :) glad you understand what i was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#load').html(...).load(function(){
  // what to do when its loaded.
});
```

Comment: Close but the function isn't working, i mean it is loading the thing in the html but then the function isn't doing anything

Comment: I alerted to see if the function is being proccess but nothing alerts

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event handler:

> Description: Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Do stuff with the HTML
});
```